# Get current road speed limit

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to develop a Javascript program which gets the current speed limit of the current road. I have tried using using the Overpass API, but that only returns an empty XML file:

```
/interpreter?node(around:10, 40.7127, 74.0059)[maxspeed];out;
```

I haven't implemented this into my code yet, testing it on Firefox.

Why is the XML file empty, and are there any other free online resources which can be used to get the speed limit of a road at coordinates `x`,`y`?

***Note:*** I would prefer if it supported speed limits in the UK

Comment: Can you give us an actual example of a query that you are trying to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons your query returns an empty result:

- You are querying in a very sparsely mapped region
- You are querying for *nodes* instead of *ways*

Try this query instead:

```
way
  (around:70, 51.0483, 13.7495)
  [maxspeed];
(._;>;);
out;
```

See the [result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/aSW).

Comment: What does `(._;>;);` do?

Comment: Its a recursion. It tells Overpass API to include all *nodes*  referenced by the *ways* returned by your query. It can be omitted but it is required if you are interested in the geometry of your ways. Ways don't have coordinates themselves, instead their geometry is defined by the nodes they are referencing.

Comment: @BetaDecay Would you mind accepting my answer if it solves your question? :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot :)

Comment: Third reason: the URL was incorrect to start with, as `data=` is missing after `interpreter?` ... overpass turbo will create the correct URL for you by clicking on Export -> raw data directly from Overpass API